# the operator += is undefined Java array

Tags: java, undefined, operator-keyword

Here is my first class for the Array, just making a simple Die array and Array list.

```
public class Die
{
    private int total;
   private final int MAX = 6;  // maximum face value

   private int faceValue;  // current value showing on the die

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets the initial face value.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public Die()
   {
      faceValue = 1;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Rolls the die and returns the result.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int roll()
   {
      faceValue = (int)(Math.random() * MAX) + 1;

      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value mutator.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void setFaceValue(int value)
   {
      faceValue = value;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Face value accessor.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public int getFaceValue()
   {
      return faceValue;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Returns a string representation of this die.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);

      return result;
   }

}
```

next is the array and arraylist I'm having trouble with the operator trying to retrieve the total for the array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayWithDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Die dieArray[] = new Die[10];
        ArrayList<Die> set1 = new ArrayList<Die>();


        for(int i=0; i<dieArray.length; i++)
        {
            dieArray[i] = new Die();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<dieArray.length; i++)
        {
            dieArray[i].roll();
            System.out.println(dieArray[i]);
        } 
        int total = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <dieArray.length; i++)
        {
            total += dieArray[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);


        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            set1.add(i, new Die());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <set1.size(); i++)
        {
            set1.get(i).roll();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <set1.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(set1.get(i));
        }
        int total1 = 0;
        for(int i=0; i <set1.size(); i++)
        {
            total1 += set1.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why I am receiving this error? I've tried most things I can think of except for modifying the original class, after this I will compare totals between the array and arraylist but I am confident that I can code that part myself. Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `total += dieArray[i].getFaceValue()`?

Comment: Please include the exact error message and point to source code line it refers to.

Comment: The last loop makes no sense. It's calculating `int total1 = set1.size() * set1.size();`. Did you mean `total1 += set1.get(i).getFaceValue();`?

Comment: why not you use total = total + dieArray[i].getFaceValue();

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a `Die` Object to an Integer.

Maybe you want

```
total += dieArray[i].getFaceValue ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are doing

```
total += dieArray[i];
```

put

```
total += dieArray[i].getFaceValue();
```

Your issue I believe is that you are trying to add a type Die to an int.